# Grammatical concord requires that the possessive pronoun following "which of us" be in the singular

Tags: agreement, possessive-determiners, which-what

[Page 458 of Fowler's Concise Dictionary of Modern English Usage](https://books.google.es/books?id=w2NjCgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA458&dq=%22Which%20of%20us%20would%20wish%20to%20be%20ill%20in%22&hl=es&pg=PA458#v=onepage&q=%22Which%20of%20us%20would%20wish%20to%20be%20ill%20in%22&f=false) reads

> *Which of us would wish to be ill in **his or her** kitchen, especially when it is
> also the family living room?*
>
> Grammatical concord requires that the possessive pronoun following *which of us* should be in the singular.

**WHICH** https://oed.com/oed2/00284418

Why is it so?

Comment: 'Which of us are ready to leave?' is fine. But here, the 'addressing the singular individual within a plural audience' technique is being used (cf 'I recommend that you take your wife a bouquet of flowers to reaffirm your love for her' when addressing a large audience of married men). I'd _prefer_ the 'addressing the singular individual within a plural audience' technique in Fowler's example sentence, but it's by no means _required_.

Comment: Surely the example means 'Which one of us...?' or 'Is there any one of us who...?'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth There is a generic singular **we/us/ourself** (vs. a group regarded collectively: _**We** see **ourself** as the biggest club in Britain_) https://oed.com/oed2/00165916

Comment: See ["which of you are'' or ''which of you is''?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/136579/which-of-you-are-or-which-of-you-is/136582) on English Language Learners.

Comment: @FumbleFingers What grammatical persons can **your** be in _Which of you forgot **your** coat_?

Comment: _Your_ is second person only, either singular or plural. Similarly, _you_.

Comment: Obviously, ***your*** can only be a "singular" reference in *Which of you forgot your **coat**?*, even though preceding ***you*** refers to "plural" addressees. So if you really wanted to put me on the spot you should have asked about *Which of you forgot your **gloves**?*  (or perhaps  *Which of **us** uses **their** left hand[s] to write?*, if you want to be *really* awkward! :) But to be honest, my answer to those questions is *I don't know and I don't care and I don't see what use it is to "know" something like that.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers "obviously"? elaborate a bit please

Comment: Because "coat" is singular, and we know that in the real world there's a one-to-one correspondence of one person to one coat. Note that the "plurality" of ***your*** in *Which of you forgot your coat?* is entirely independent of the plurality of ***Which of*** (or equivalent ***Who among***). In other examples, the plurality of the "wh-clause" would be governed by the associated verb. Thus: *Which of us **are** happy with this example?* and *Who among you **is** without sin?* are both fine.

Comment: @FumbleFingers What grammatical persons can **yours** be in _Which of you forgot **yours**_?

Comment: As John already said, ***yours*** can be singular or plural. And if all we've got is just the basic utterance ***Which of you forgot yours**?*, there's insufficient context to take it any further, so it's "ambiguous" whether the subject ("which of you") is singular or plural. And I assume that by *What grammatical persons can **yours** be?*, you're asking whether it refers to something[s] of ***one*** or ***multiple*** addressees. But even that implies the speaker *knows* how many of "you" meet the condition, which isn't always the case. Language simply isn't as precise as you seem to think.